# Lebesgue Integral vs Completion of L1

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

There's a general result which says any metric space can be embedded within a complete metric space(or in other words, the metric space can be completed).

If one completes the space of L1 Riemann integrable functions, how does this differ from the lebesgue integral?

Certainly the metric completion argument is very simple, skips measure theory altogether and gets nice results like MCT and DCT.

What are the reasons to prefer to measure-theoretic construction?

Comment: How do you "skips measure theory altogether and gets nice results like MCT and DCT"? With Riemann integration, let's say we can define $L^p$ norm on the space of Riemann integrable functions and compete it to get the $L^p$ space (for finite $p$). But that wouldn't tell us what exactly the elements of $L^p$ are, except for that they are equivalent classes of sequences of continuous functions. With Lebesgue integral, we can regard them as Lebesgue integrable functions.

Comment: https://mast.queensu.ca/~speicher/Section12.pdf

Comment: In that note, continuous functions on $[0,1]$ are regarded as in an abstractly defined $L^p$ space (the space of bounded continuous functionals on continuous functions), and MCT/DCT are proved for elements in that $L^p$ space with an abstractly defined integration (a bounded linear operator on $L^p$). Having a concrete definition of Lebesgue measure allows us to associate these $L^p$ elements with functions on $[0,1]$. Very often we are more interested in the latter.

Comment: Say we want to integrate a "bad" function. Lebesgue measure allows us to put that function into a complete space, approximate it by continuous functions (MCT/DCT allow us to do this pointwise), and approximate its integration by integrating its continuous approximations. As far as I know that's what motivated the idea of Lebesgue integral: we want to study more than just nice continuous functions (e.g., how bad can a function be to still be "integrable"). Lebesgue measure bridges the the abstract construction to concrete examples.

Comment: Correction to a typo: "... on $[0,1]$ are regarded as elements in an abstractly defined..."

Comment: the main reason is that it is far easier to work with measures and explicit constructions that with abstract functional analysis

Comment: Peter Lax "Rethinking the Lebesgue Integral" 2009 https://www.jstor.org/stable/40391247 sketches what a real analysis course might look like which first defined $L^1([0,1])$ as the metric completion of $C([0,1])$ and then asked the question "can we give a more explicit description of elements of this completion?" He shows how this naturally leads to the concept of Lebesgue measure. It seems pretty well motivated to me!